# How do read the content of a file in s3 bucket into ansible variable

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

Need to do a file lookup in ansible but the file is on s3 and not local, how do I read the content of the remote file on s3, doing something like this:

`{{lookup('file','s3://examplebucket/conf_file.json') }}`

Answer (score 0):

The lookup plugin only works for files that exist on the host where you are running Ansible from, it will not allow you to fetch remote objects like in your example. See Ansible docs http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html

To retrieve an object  from an s3 bucket you could use the following module http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/s3_module.html

Note however that is has a dependency on boto.
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/